# Google analytics lost conversions

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

we have recently implemented social login to our website. We are running ads to that website and after implementing the social login we lost all conversion data - everything is accounted to facebook.

Also we have kind of "sub-website" shop-domain.com where are some products that are sold separately and user can migrate between domain.com and shop-domain.com and vice versa. Can this loose conversions as well?

My question is:

how can we configure analytics / ads / website to correctly count the conversions?

What have I done:

In google analytics documentation I found something called linker to fix user migration between domains and page referrer after login. But it doesnt seem to help

```
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', {
        'linker': {
            'domains': ['domain.com', 'domain.eu', 'shop-domain.com', 'shop-domain.eu']
        },
        'page_referrer':'domain.com'
    });
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this issue is a bit complicated to solve over a forum discussion like this. You will probably need to hire an expert to audit your setup and look for the cause of the problem.

But let me try giving you some hints and point you in the right direction so that you can debug on your own if you like.

If the Facebook login is the only addition to the code recently and you started seeing conversions credited to it since setting it up, then the probable culprit is that FB login. In that case, one of the possible solutions is to exclude it from referrers in GA, but that might or might not resolve the issue, and it might require bypassing it in some other ways (through GA filters for example).

If the actual problem appeared even before the FB login and the traffic sources for the conversions were not accurate (but back then, some other traffic source was taking the most significant chunk of the conversion sources, and you didn't see it as suspicious), then the something might be happening with the GA setup. In most of the cases, in GA subdomains shouldn't need any Linker parameters for the traffic sources to be credited properly, and you most probably should remove the Linker between them completely. Check if both domain and the subdomain have the cookieDomain set to "auto" and it should be fine.